# Handle clickable item in onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer layout and I want to when I click the item then navigate to another intent,
I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hallo berghaasiALSj ia",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, UtamaClass.class));
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UtamaClass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Do you have this statement
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setNavigationItemSelectedListener(OnNavigationItemSelectedListener listener)` of your `NavigationView`

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                   //your code
                }
             }

        });
```